# REVOKE_ACCESS : how to remove 'revoke' an inherited ACE?

Tags: windows, acl, file-permissions

I have the code below working for various ACE changes and adds and revoking - it just does NOT work when I try and remove an ACE that is in the ACL (clearly there), but this ACE is inherited.

The `SetEntriesInAcl()` for revoke of non-inherited ACEs works, reduces the ACL ACE count and the following `SetNamedSecurityInfo()` does the revoke and the ACE is gone.

When the ACE is inherited though - both these API return `SUCCESS` - but the ACE is not removed/revoked, the ACL ACE count remains the same.

I have also coded doing `DeleteAce()` but when that DACL is used in `SetNamedSecurityInfo()` again the RC is `SUCCESS` (no return codes) and the ACE remains for the folder I am dealing with - clearly there is a trick on how to remove an inherited ACE.

Btw, for the same folder in question SUBINACL command line tool does the revoke of this inherited ACE without problem.

```
                 if( EqualSid( pSid_for_ace, pSid )  )
                    { /* ACE SID matched edit SID */

                    if( cmd_se_edit == SE_REM )
                       { /* remove */

                       rem_lst[ ace_idx ] = x;

                       exp_ace[ ace_idx ].grfAccessPermissions = dwAccessRights;
                       exp_ace[ ace_idx ].grfAccessMode        = REVOKE_ACCESS;
                       exp_ace[ ace_idx ].grfInheritance       = dwInheritance;
                       exp_ace[ ace_idx ].Trustee.TrusteeForm  = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
                       exp_ace[ ace_idx ].Trustee.TrusteeType  = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
                       exp_ace[ ace_idx ].Trustee.ptstrName    = pSid;

                       if( ace_idx < (REMMAX-1) ) ++ace_idx;

                       } /* remove */

                    } /* ACE SID matched edit SID */

              pBA = (BYTE *)p_aceHdr;

              ace_sz = p_aceHdr->AceSize;

              p_aceHdr = (PACE_HEADER)&pBA[ ace_sz ];

              } /* loop through ACEs */


           // Create a new ACL that merges the new ACE
           // into the existing DACL.

           if( ace_idx )
              { /* ACEs to remove */

              dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl( ace_idx, &exp_ace[0],
                                                        pDacl, &pNewDacl );
              if( ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes )
                 {
                 printf( "SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n", dwRes );
                 goto Cleanup2;
                 }

              // Attach the new ACL as the object's DACL.

              dwRes = SetNamedSecurityInfo(    ObjName,
                                               ObjectType,
                                               DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                               NULL,
                                               NULL,
                                              pNewDacl,
                                               NULL );

              if( ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes )
                 {
                 rc3 = GetLastError();
                 printf( "SetNamedSecurityInfo Error %u\n", dwRes );
                 goto Cleanup2;
                 }

              } /* ACEs to remove */
```

Comment: The access permissions mask and inheritance settings are identical to the ACE being revoked - per MS guidance (the only guidance I have found.) - Setting this ACE with the above code results in a new ACE that matches what I set -- but the original inherited ACE remains -- the ACL grew by 1 for this test - then the revoke of this test ACE worked correctly -- once again the original inherited ACE remains.

Comment: Removing an inherited ACE breaks the rules for ACLs.  The high-level APIs won't let you do this; the low-level APIs will, but you shouldn't.  Instead, turn off inheritance on the target object and copy those ACEs that you want to keep, or consider using a Deny entry instead.

Comment: Thanks Harry - programmatically (via the APIs) **how** does one turn off inheritance on my targeted object? -- I have not been able to do this (grrr)..... Once inheritance is turned off - I know how to copy an ACE - in your comment you say to copy the ACEs I wish to keep - copy them to where? and once there how do you put them back to the "folder's" Security Descriptor -- I know some APIs to do that -- I am curious as to your thoughts/insight.... thanks again, regards Kevin Waite

Comment: My first goal here is to make a folder off the root that is like "c:\program files" call it "c:\ti001" --- my second goal is to have two groups called my_admins and my_users -- I want the "c:\ti001" folder to have these groups added to its ACL .... first things first -- need to remove "authenticated users"

Comment: Does the new folder need to inherit other (unknown) permissions from its parent, or do you already know exactly what permissions you want the folder to have?

Comment: Hi Harry, I know exactly what the ACL should be -- just can not get it to be that -- starting with the pesky inherited ACEs.... This needs/must be done with the API not command line tool. So bottom line it does not neet to inherit ACEs from the root -- however some from the root -- such as Administrators -- will have to be created anew - again as is c:\program files. Btw - why are there two ACEs for SIDs like Administrators - with one being empty....

Comment: My main need for help is how to remove the inherirt flags/bits/settings -- and then I think I can rebuild ACE by ACE.... the children in my new folder (containers and files) need to inherit from c:\ti001 and same for grandkids too..... thanks so much -- all the best -- regards, Kevin Waite

Comment: There are often two inherited ACEs for a given SID on a container object: one is applied to the container only, the other to child objects only.  They could be replaced with a single ACE without changing the meaning, but that's the way Windows implements inheritance.

Comment: Kevin Did you remove the inherited ace successfully? I can disable the inheritance falg of the ace and I also can remove that ace from the GUI of file's security when I right click on the file and click the properties. However, why cannot I remove the ace using DeleteAce() function, but it's possible on the GUI? Thanks, Zhou

Comment: @Zhou: please post a new question, including your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present it looks as if you are retrieving the existing ACL from the folder and modifying it.  In your situation, you will be better off building a new ACL from scratch.  To do this, build an array of EXPLICIT_ACCESS structures describing the permissions that you want, and call [SetEntriesInAcl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) passing NULL for OldAcl.

To apply the new DACL, call SetNamedSecurityInfo in the same way you do in your code, but pass `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` for SecurityInfo.  The [PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag disables inheritance from the parent.

Comment: Thanks Harry! This worked. For those seeking more indepth reading/info check these two urls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163885.aspx#S3  -and-  http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleH.html